# Exit windows popup messages to be customized with styles css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I want the message "Leaving page will cause loss of data" to be bold. could you please help me?

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
    return "Leaving page will cause loss of data";
}).unload(function() {
    // what if they choose 'leave this page'; 
});
```

Comment: The message box which is shown is controlled by the browser/OS at a lower level than JS has access to. You cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no , you can not style alerts or confirm messages that are shown by the browser.  What you can do is write your own modal to pop up , jquery has code that makes that process pretty easy bootstrap does as well.  They will be far from the default browser looking alert , but they can be customized to look anyway you would like

Comment: But that's not possible to use it as modal, in strict term speaking. Meaning, you can not block browser behaviour redirecting/closing the page. So here, it is useless

Comment: Ture , so the answer goes back to NO